# Horizontally Center Text In Fixed Position Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, position

I have text in the following div but I cannot seem to get it to align center:

```
<div class="banner_tron">
            <div class="bg-box-100-grey">
                    <span class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-60 center color-white">Hello World</span>
                    <div class="div-wrapper">
                    <p class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-20 center color-white">Have a Wonderful Day</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The CSS for this code is as follows:

```
.banner_tron{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}     
   .center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    } 

/* background-boxing */
.bg-box-100-grey{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  rgba(108,108,108, .7);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}
.ex-lrg-60 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I have tried several different suggestions for the .center class but nothing seems to work (javascript positioning, align items, and webkit transformations). Any suggestions on why this isn't working and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `text-align:center` to your `.banner_tron`

```css
.banner_tron{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align:center;
}     
   .center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom:auto;
    } 

/* background-boxing */
.bg-box-100-grey{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  rgba(108,108,108, .7);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}
.ex-lrg-60 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_tron">
  <div class="bg-box-100-grey">
    <span class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-60 color-white">Hello World</span>
    <div class="div-wrapper">
      <p class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-20 center color-white">Have a Wonderful Day</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Skip `center` and add `text-align: center` to the `bg-box-100-grey` rule

```css
.banner_tron{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

/* background-boxing */
.bg-box-100-grey{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  rgba(108,108,108, .7);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
  text-align: center
}
.ex-lrg-60 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_tron">
            <div class="bg-box-100-grey">
                    <span class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-60 color-white">Hello World</span>
                    <div class="div-wrapper">
                    <p class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-20 center color-white">Have a Wonderful Day</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Or change the `center` class like below and add it to the `bg-box-100-grey` element's class

```css
.banner_tron{
  bottom: 0;
  height: 150px;
  left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

/* background-boxing */
.bg-box-100-grey{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color:  rgba(108,108,108, .7);
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    border: none;
}
.ex-lrg-60 {
    font-size: 60px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner_tron">
            <div class="bg-box-100-grey center">
                    <span class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-60 color-white">Hello World</span>
                    <div class="div-wrapper">
                    <p class="SansFontBold ex-lrg-20 center color-white">Have a Wonderful Day</p>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```